# File Server: to zip or not to zip

Tags: filesystems, file-server

My workplace shares a SMB fileserver for storing documents and files that we receive from clients. The contents of these directories are usually a mixture of Documents (PDF, .docx) and images. Clients send us whole nested directories (from a wide range of environments), and this leads to some very messy paths.

A proposed solution to this is to store all files/directories that we receive from clients within their zipped folder. I feel like this puts an unnecessary burden on our users, as they cannot search through zipped directories, and need to copy and unzip all directories locally to access any necessary data. But, it does remove the need to manage those messy paths.

Am I missing something? Is there a tangible benefit (besides a "cleaner" directory structure) to zipping everything up and making all the work happen on local users machines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.ifiltershop.com/downloads/zipfilter/readme.html - add ZIP files to Windows search indexing.

Windows' NTFS compressed folders will store the data compressed, yet be transparent to your end users: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101195&seqNum=3

> this leads to some very messy paths.

So? How much money and effort are you willing to spend for this aesthetic "problem", and why? Surely "not being able to find documents" is infinitely more problematic than "when I imagine what the folder tree is, in my head it's ugly"?

> Am I missing something? Is there a tangible benefit (besides a "cleaner" directory structure) to zipping everything up and making all the work happen on local users machines?

Mainly that it will take up less disk space overall, also that one compressed file will transfer faster - e.g. onto a backup - than lots of small files.

Answer (score 0):

Individually zipping directories is not super efficient for disk space usage reasons. Deduplication at the volume level would be better, or enabling compression.

"Cleaner" directory structure is certainly a puzzler. I don't really know what this supposed to mean.

It's unclear why you need users to search through the files provided to you by clients, but if it's a common task I believe you. From what I understand, however, .zip files are treated entirely like folders by Windows, which means that they are also included in searches. There are third party tools like Powergrep that also let you search across .zip files.

The only benefit I can think of that is legitimate for zipping the directories is to preserve file permissions within the .zip file. Windows automatically inherits folder permissions which can mess things up if you move a folder to a subfolder of a different folder. Keeping everything zipped avoids this issue when you want to deploy the folder to its final location.